# String parameters not sending to activity from local notification

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, localnotification

I am currently trying to send a local notification with an action. The action will push a string to the activity when selected. Unfortunately, when I try to pass a String I am unable to receive it on the activity, I have multiple log statements with different objects to see if maybe the system is recognizing it as something else but no luck. Event when I tried to send it in as a bundle, the bundle is sent but not the string! if I pass an int it works great! Any help would be appreciated, and yes I have been digging around for this and tried multiple solutions.

Code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intent.setAction("action");

        intent.putExtra("idforaction", 12345);
        //intent.putExtra("test", "test message");
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("othertest","test message 2");
        intent.putExtra("test", bundle);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

MainActivity:

```
int notificationNum = getIntent().getIntExtra(idfoaction, -1);
        Log.e(TAG, "get Extras " + notificationNum);

        Log.e(TAG, "STRING? " + getIntent().getStringExtra("test"));
        Log.e(TAG, "CHARSEQ? " + getIntent().getCharSequenceExtra("test"));
        Log.e(TAG, "CHARS?" + (getIntent().getCharArrayExtra("test") != null ? getIntent().getCharArrayExtra("test").length + "" : "null"));
        Log.e(TAG, "PARCELABLE?" + (getIntent().getParcelableExtra("test") != null ? getIntent().getParcelableExtra("test").toString(): "null"));
        Log.e(TAG, "BUNDLE?" + (getIntent().getBundleExtra("test") != null ? "not null" : "null"));
        Log.e(TAG, "BUNDLE?" + (getIntent().getExtras() != null ? "not null" : "null"));
        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "bundle " + getIntent().getExtras().getString("othertest", ""));
            Log.e(TAG, "bundle " + getIntent().getExtras().get("othertest"));
        }
```

Comment: check this library. Annotation based and also it involves Intent data binding: https://github.com/kostasdrakonakis/android_navigator

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("my_key", "my_key_value");
```

And read:

```
Intent intent = getIntent()
String myValue = intent.getStringExtra("my_key"); // "my_key_value"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately I tried this method but the string appears blank.

Comment: @paul590 Check what you put there by this key